# Populate Session UserID whilst doing a SQL insert via a form

Tags: php, sql, session-variables

I want to record the user ID from the current logged in user who enters data into the form which in turn is recorded to a database table

At present the insert query is running and updating all but the user id..the user id variable is definitely working as I am able to echo it out without any issues on the same page

Code is as follows;

```
$barcode = $_POST['barcode'];
  $weight = $_POST['weight'];
  $userId = $_SESSION['userId'];

//error handling begins

  // check for any empty inputs.
  if (empty($barcode) || empty($weight)) {
    header("Location: ../record.php?error=emptyfields&barcode=".$barcode."&weight=".$weight);
    exit();
  }
  //we check if valid barcode entered. In this case ONLY letters and numbers.
  else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $barcode)) {
    header("Location: ../record.php?error=invalidbarcode&barcode=".$weight);
    exit();
  }
  // check for an invalid weight. In this case ONLY numbers.
  else if (!preg_match("/^[0-9].*$/", $weight)) {
    header("Location: ../record.php?error=invalidweight&barcode=".$barcode);
    exit();
  }
  else {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO trimrecords (barcode, weight, createdby) VALUES (?,?,?);";
        // initialize a new statement using the connection from the dbh.inc.php file.
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        //  prepare  SQL statement AND check if there are any errors with it.
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
          // If there is an error send the user back to the record page.
          header("Location: ../record.php?error=sqlerror");
          exit();
        }
        else {

          // If there is no error continue the script!

          // bind the type of parameters we expect to pass into the statement, and bind the data from the user.
          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssi", $barcode, $weight, $userId);
          // execute the prepared statement and send it to the database!
          // data is registered to Db at this stage
          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
          // send back with success
          header("Location: ../record.php?record=success");
          exit();

        }
}
```

Comment: Try putting intval around the $userID

Comment: @RichardHousham could you expand on this please bud?

Comment: try this
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssi", $barcode, $weight, intval($userId));

Comment: Just to ask is userID an int? Also if it's not entering - what does it enter instead - null?

Comment: after putting intval around userId it is now outputting a 0 into the created by column on DB! so we are making progress that's for sure! But zero isn't the correct value! on sql db it is set as int(11)

Comment: Although I believe a 0 value is a failure?

Comment: Yeah, so your userId isn't an interger. thus your problem.

Comment: Have you got session_start(); above your session code?

Comment: Yea session variables are being passed to page no problem as their in the header and I can echo them out! Column on database is definitely set to an integer with max length of 11!

Comment: maybe try some debugging here and set $userID to 6 or something. Make sure that can go in. The examples in the code http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php show the variables being set after the bind. Anything in that?

Comment: Yea when I declare a specific value for variable it works e.g. $userId = 6; It must be something to do with how the value is being passed from the stored session

Comment: ... although I have to remove the intval() from around the variable in bind statement for it to work even whilst declaring a specific numeric value..?

Comment: Got it working - because I was using an include file to perform the error handling/sql actions it was excluded from the header page which had the session start statement at the top! flags a million for all your help @RichardHousham

Comment: Np. Yeah that'll do it for you. Would have thought your $conn would be in that file?
Ah maybe you have another file - database.php np. FYI have a look at https://github.com/envms/fluentpdo I've used it before and if you have a mysql database it plays well out the box. Just makes it easier with the bindings and stuff.

Comment: Can you just accept my answer (get some points :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `session_start()` to the top and all worked.